# Convert string of OrderedDict to multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe that is in form of an OrderedDict (type: object):

```
 ColumnA   

 [OrderedDict([('MaStRNummer', 'SME949781471367'), ('Einheittyp', 'Windeinheit'), ('Einheitart', 'Stromerzeugungseinheit')])]
```

I want to convert into multiple columns like this:

```
    MaStRNummer      Einheittyp    Einheitart    
0   SME949781471367  Windeinheit   Stromerzeugungseinheit
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your data look like this which includes a `ColumnA`

```
df=pd.Series([OrderedDict([('MaStRNummer', 'SME949781471367'), 
                        ('Einheittyp', 'Windeinheit'), 
                        ('Einheitart', 'Stromerzeugungseinheit')])]
,name='ColumnA').to_frame()
```

Then to expand the ordered dict, we could apply `pd.Series` on it,

```
df.ColumnA.apply(pd.Series)
```

To merge it with original dataset, try

```
df.join(df.ColumnA.apply(pd.Series))
```